# Field calculator expression running in Attribute Table and not in QGIS Processing Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, field-calculator, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I am using QGIS 3.10.

I use the **Field Calculator** in the **Attributes table** and run the operation : `"FieldA" - "FieldB"`, where `"FieldA"` and `"FieldB"` are height distances in meter with a double type (i.e. 2,45). The operation run smoothly.

Now, when I do the same operation using the **Field Calculator** within the **Processing Modeler**, it does not run the operation without failure. The message error on the **Output Preview** in the **Expression Editor** is reporting `Cannot convert "FieldA" to double`. So it seems that the coding of the expression is not equivalent in both **Field Calculator**.

In the **Field Calculator** within the **Processing Modeler**, I tried :

- `"FieldA" - "FieldB"`
- `manual input:fields then @FieldA - @FieldB`
- `to_real("FieldA") - to_real("FieldB")`
- `to_real(replace(to_string("FieldA"), ',', '.')) - to_real(replace(to_string("FieldB"), ',', '.'))`

Would anyone have encountered the same issue?